# Typing the ZIP code doesn't yield the company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On Careers, if I type in our postal code (48326), it does not reveal our company page even though our postal code is entered as 48326 on our Careers company page. If I instead do a search by company name as `thyssenkrupp`, then our company page appears.

I believe most candidates will first search by city or postal code rather than by name, and we could be missing great talent. Is this a bug or does the search ignore the postal code or what gives?

Answer (score 11):

<s>This is by design. If a company isn't listing any jobs, they will only show up for searches by name.</s>

This is partly because we are (admittedly) running a business and think you should buy job listings, and also because somebody searching on Careers is likely looking for a job and will be disappointed to find a company near them which is not actually hiring.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196072/allow-me-to-find-companies-by-zip-code-job-listings-or-not/198007#198007). We now show company pages for all searches.

Comment: i really dont like this answer as we will soon be buying into a job listing and removing us from the company pages gives us no visibility.  why would it show for name but not postal code...this is bound to confuse future potential customers.

Comment: @JonH: Your question was " Is this a bug or does the search ignore the postal code or what gives?", which David answered. It doesn't matter if you like the answer or not - it's the answer to the question you asked. It's not a bug, and he explained the reasons it's not.

Comment: Seems like a fair response to downvote if you don't like this answer. How else will we get feedback? I suppose someone could open a [tag:feature-request]

Comment: @David: I wasn't accusing JonH of downvoting. I was addressing the comment that said "I really don't like this answer" and explaining why. The objection isn't to your answer, but to the overall topic of the question, and they're not the same thing. Your answer was fine, and shouldn't be what the objection is based upon. (I upvoted your answer, BTW, because it was well written and clearly answered the question asked.)

Comment: Boy - I don't like this answer either. I'd like to know about the companies in my area whether or not they've realized they're in need of my talents. ;) Seriously, though, it kind of kills networking opportunities. Put companies with job listings at the top, or gray out the ones without a listing, but I'd still like to know they exist.

Comment: @JonH - I [opened a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196072/allow-me-to-find-companies-by-zip-code-job-listings-or-not).