# Posting with all lower case letters didn't allow me to submit my question

Tags: support, quality-filter

I posted this question earlier [Typing the ZIP code doesn't yield the company page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195998/typing-zip-code-doesnt-yield-company-page) while using my google tv.  As soon as I hit submit, to submit my question, I got an error with something to the effect of my post content was not of good quality.  I retread it over and over and tried to submit and it continued to error out.  I then realised because I was using my google tv I had ignored capitilizing for instance the first letter of my initial paragraph.  Using that darn google keyboard was dinky so I avoided capitalising.

As soon as i fixed that first word just by making it a capital letter as well as the first word in my second paragraph it worked fine.  Seemed a bit odd

Comment: Why do you find that odd? Proper capitalization shouldn't affect a post's quality? I certainly don't like when people don't capitalize things, and (before someone says it) typing on your TV is not at all an excuse not to use proper capitalization.

Comment: Possibly a more specific message would have been good. Otherwise the system seems to have worked

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's part of the Stack Exchange quality filter - the automated thingy used to keep posts matching certain criteria out of the system. In this case, the system is assuming that any grammatically-close-to-correct post should have at least *one* capital letter *somewhere*.

In this case, it did its job - namely making you improve the post by just a little. Every little improvement you make is one that someone else doesn't have to make.

> #### Every little improvement you make is one someone else doesn't have to make.

This simple statement is the reason for many of the filters that seem strange in SE. When you encounter one of these filters, your job is to get through it - 99.9% of the time, you will need to make a *little improvement* to get through it.

Comment: "Every little improvement you make is one that someone else doesn't have to make." <--- This is a beautiful statement. It's also thousands of people who won't be negatively affected by someone typing on Google TV.